# How can I determine if this draws a triangle?

Tags: trigonometry

Given a compass and these instructions

```
 1. Go 50 meters 7 degrees
 2. Go 50 meters 127 degrees
 3. Go 50 meters 247 degrees
```

**Questions**

How can I use trigonometry to determine if I've plotted a triangle?
Change  Step #3 to 50 meters at 255 degrees. How could I illustrate or show how calculations are different?

Comment: You should make a sketch or even better use a tool like geogebra to construct the walk. Note that the angles are given as relative to north (i.e. relative to the vector $\pmatrix{0\\1}$).

Comment: Because the three lengths are equal, if it draws a triangle, it must be equilateral. Try to find out by how much you turn at each time. Does it agree with what angles the triangle has to have?

Comment: For other inputs, you can use law of sines to determine if the ratios are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that you walk the same distance in each direction: if this is a triangle it must be equilateral. As the outer angles of an equilateral triangle are $120$ degrees, your direction of movement will have to increase by this amount each time you change direction. As $127-7=120$ and $247-127=120$ you see that these instructions will in fact form a triangle.

If you instead replace $247$ by $255$ you get $255-127=128\ne 120$, so in this case the instructions do not draw a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

This plot[image]

Illustrates your walk and how you can prove it: It's equilateral if it is a triangle (All distances are $50m$ (Scaled $1:10$). Using various cross-angles you find that
$$7^\circ + (180^\circ - 127^\circ) \stackrel!= 60^\circ \qquad \checkmark\\
180^\circ - (247^\circ - 127^\circ) \stackrel!= 60^\circ \qquad \checkmark$$
Now use a congruence theorem to see you are done. If we alter step 3 only, we cannot end up with a triangle because it will move the endpoint away from the starting point.